# Uploading multiple dynamic files to laravel from vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to upload multiple files with it's respective data from vue to laravel. I'm getting the files in vue (on vue console) but when submitting the form and doing **dd($request['new_members']);** on the laravel controller, it returns the result below:

[image: Result dd]

The other data is available but the file value is gone.

**Vue**

```
<div class="row mt-2" v-for="(new_member,index) in new_members" :key="index">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>NAME</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="new_member.name" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>POSITION</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="new_member.position" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>IMAGE</label>
        <input type="file" @change="onFileChange(index,$event)" name="file" ref="fileInput" required/>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-12 rounded-0 float-right"  @click.prevent="addMoreMember()">ADD MORE</button>

<script>
data(){
    return{
        new_members:[{
            name:'',
            position:'',
            file:''
        }]
    }
},
methods:{
    addMoreMember(){
        this.new_members.push({name:'',position:'',file:''})
    },
    onFileChange(index,$event) {
        this.new_members[index].file =  $event.target.files[0]
    },
    submit(){
        let form = new FormData()
        form.append('new_members',JSON.stringify(this.new_members));
        form.append('content_team', this.content_team);
        axios.post('/api/mainpage/addNewMember',form).then(res=>{

        }) 
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiple file uploading concepts,

> You need to create an API service for upload files only and returning that response return `string for accessing uploaded file path`,

For every file uploading, You need to call this API services that you created.
And the final page submission you just send the file path `string` where you got from the file uploading API services

> I hope you are getting my points   ❤